# Using Google Maps in RequireJS with async

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, requirejs

I'm in China, and my project is in German. When I develop, I wish to use: http://ditu.google.cn/maps

For my local development, then in German, it can switch to http://maps.googleapi.com/maps

So I put my require.config.js like:

```
require.config({
    // List of all the dependencies
    paths: {
        google: [
            '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false',
            '//ditu.google.cn/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'
        ]
    }
})
```

When the first link times out, it will try the second one. But when I run my project, I get this error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I played with angularJS and GoogleMaps (loaded asynchronously, inside a directive). I didn't use requireJS. Checkout this: https://github.com/ericpanorel/AngularGmap especially the index2.html part. Maybe you'll get some ideas.

Comment: sorry, It seems not what I want...I need to adapt url by using timeout, dependent on witch environment is.